# Is there a "ForwardPDF" tool available?

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, tools, srcltx, forward-inverse-search

When I am working on a big document, I find the srcltx package to be extremely useful. However, I also really like the hyperref package. Is it possible to use both?  In particular, is there a way to use ForwardDVI and inverse search with PDFLaTeX?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If using pdflatex you should switch to using the SyncTeX patch (included in pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.8 and later), which is generally enabled with the flag `-synctex=1` (TeX live 2010 and MiKTeX 2.8/2.9, at least).

Not all PDF viewers support it yet though. 
You can see it working in TexWorks IDE.

Comment: I second this suggestion. On Mac OS X, Skim + Aquamacs play nicely together and with synctex.  I use it all the time.

Comment: Just to point out that SyncTeX is something that needs to be built in to the engine, which it is in the TeX Live 2009/2010 and MikTeX 2.8 binaries. TeXworks will turn on using SyncTeX by default, which makes it a good choice to see SyncTeX in action, but you can set up other editors to use it (I'm not sure which ones use it 'out of the box' at the moment).

Answer (score 6):

[SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/index.html) allows forward and inverse searching, but is Windows only. It works seamlessly with MikTeX 2.8 and WinEdt 6.0. I haven't tried it with TeXLive or other windows editors.