# Change text background within paragraph (with automatic linebreaks)

Tags: color, line-breaking, paragraphs, backgrounds

How do I change the text color as well as the text background color for e.g. a sentence within a paragraph? I know \textcolor for coloring the font and \colorbox for background coloring [http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors]. Unfortunately \colorbox will not perform a linebreak. Is there any solution for that?

I want to make MY changes in a PDF document visible for review. I know some other approaches like diffpdf, oder pdftotext and then diff.. But I thought this should be an easy task.

Thanks for your comments.

Edit: Hm, appetite comes with eating: Unfortunately the \hl command from soul and all other approaches I saw does not regard whole environments like itemize, tabular. So I don't want to highlight all text inside them separately. Do you see any way around this problem?

Thanks again.

Comment: There are tools for highlighting changes: see [How to keep track of necessary changes (“todo”) for a large document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14959/2693).

Comment: Yes thanks, but I want it more visual, where exactly the highlights starts and ends. This is not possible with todonote, but I really like it for making comments on margins.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think [this question about highlighting in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for. I just needed the the highlighting as well as todonotes giving me comments and highlights in the pdf. But it does not work for environments and tabulars as well, should I update the title of my question, since it regards now also not only paragraphs.

Comment: @brubelsabs: In my opinion, you should rather ask a new (follow-up) question and provide a link to the original question.