# How to highlight paragraph (linebreak preserving) as well as itemize, tabular etc.?

Tags: environments, citing, paragraphs, highlighting, soul

I want to highlight changes which are introduced by myself in the pdf document. So far the `soul` package is very neat but it does throw errors when I want to highlight not only paragraphs but also some `itemize` environments, and I don't want to highlight the items separately. Also the `\cite{...}` command is not supported by `\hl`. I recently posted a slightly different question: [Change text background within paragraph (with automatic linebreaks)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19636/change-text-background-within-paragraph-with-automatic-linebreaks)

BTW: What I liked most over other approaches like pdfcomments etc. is that the `\hl` command from `soul` has a very exact and clear output, no icons, no clicking etc. involved. Together with `todonotes` it's very good and almost all I need.

Comment: Clumsy me: when this is a single paragraph I could clearly use \colorbox. Even with \cite commands inside. When its a phrase without \cite commands inside a paragraph I can use \hl from soul package. The only problem left is when I have a phrase with \cite commands, \hl will not work :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Concerning your question about `\hl` support for `\cite`: while `\hl{text\cite{book}}` gives an error, it works if you additionally group the `\cite` command by curly braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}
\hl{text{\cite{texbook}}}
\begin{thebibliography}{Knuth86]}
\bibitem[Knuth86]{texbook} D.E. Knuth, The TeXbook, 1986
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: highlighted \cite]

Comment: I had instead to use ``\hl{text\mbox{\cite{texbook}}}`` for it to work for me, otherwise I got "Reconstruction failed" errors.

Comment: Is there a way to automate this encapsulation into curly braces? I though of a custom macro `\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{{\cite{#1}}}`.. and then maybe `\soulregister{\mycite}{1}`?