# Highlighting text with citations and references

Tags: highlighting

I was using the package soul to highlight text. It is pretty good, except for the fact that I get errors when I try to highlight a block of text with references or a citation. For example:

```
\hl{\citet{stuff} some text...}
```

gives

```
! Argument of \@citex has an extra }.
```

Comment: Use `\hl{{\cite{stuff}} some text...}`. See [How to highlight paragraph (line break preserving) as well as `itemize`, `tabular` etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20021/5764)

Comment: This gives me ! Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed.

Comment: Also the mbox trick on that page did not work

Comment: Please create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that clearly shows what's going on. This should include a bibliography, [`natbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) (most likely) and [`soul`](http://ctan.org/pkg/soul) and that's it.