# Background color for citations in text

Tags: color, citing

What I want is that the citation in text has a yellow background (\hly{\cite{A01}} ). The color of the may be black and what is also important is that the aforementioned effect still works when there is a line break.

MWE:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,ifthen,filecontents,soul}
\usepackage[authoryear,colon,square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\def\refcolor#1#2{\expandafter\xdef\csname#1color\endcsname{#2}}
    \refcolor{A01}{green}
    \def\setbibcolor#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname#1color\endcsname\relax%
    \color{black}%
  \else%
    \color{\csname#1color\endcsname}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\harvarditem[4][]{%
 \if\relax#1\relax
   \setbibcolor{#4}\bibitem[\setbibcolor{#4}#2(#3)]{#4}%
 \else
   \bibitem[#1(#3)#2]{#4}%
 \fi
}%
\newboolean{highlighted} %Deklaration
\setboolean{highlighted}{true} %Zuweisung
\ifthenelse{\boolean{highlighted}}{
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\hly}[1]{{\sethlcolor{yellow}\hl{#1}}}
}
{
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hly}[1]{#1}
}    
\makeatother
\begin{filecontents}{mybib1.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha}
}    
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\hly{green} \citep{A01}   %\hly{\cite{A01}} 
\bibliography{mybib1}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance

Paul

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32550/106804) suggests a fix for single citations, but it does not yet seem to be working for multiple citations. It works for multiple if you use an `\mbox` but then there is no linebreak.

Comment: But this is unfortunately what I have to solve :-(

Answer (score 1):

With lualatex and the new lua-ul package you can use highlighting around cite commands without problems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\usepackage{lua-ul}
\usepackage[authoryear,colon,square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{dcu}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\hly}[1]{\highLight{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib1.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\hly{green} \citep{A01}   \hly{\cite{A01}}
\bibliography{mybib1}
\end{document}
```

[image]