# Highlighting citations along with some long sentences starting in the middle of paragraphs

Tags: citing, paragraphs, highlighting

I am trying to highlight my revised paper in latex, since when I highlight its PDF using Foxit the highlights are not shown after pressing generate PDF in journal's website.

I have some troubles: I must sometimes highlight citations, so I tried `\hl{\cite{c1}}` by `\usepackage{xcolor}`.

Some lines later, I need to highlight some paragraphs. when I tryied `\hl{long text}`, all the text was written in one line! So I decided to highlight it using `\begin{highlight}some long text \end{highlight}`

In the next part of the paper, I need just to highlight a sentence starting in the middle of a line up to in the middle of some lines next! I have tried using the `soul` package, but it wasn't possible beside `xcolor` package.

What should I do? I have these features in my paper: some citations to be highlighted, some long paragraphs to be highlighted, some sentences starting in the middle of a line (some lines long), and some figures (I know I should use framebox for figures, but I just mentioned it to be sure not any further package for solving previously mentioned parts makes problem with this simultaniously).

(Beside the problems, I even didn't see the shape of `\begin{highlight}...\end{highlight}` appropriate. Because it adds indentations to the paragraphs and changes the appearance of the paragraph)

Comment: the only stable highlighting method requires lualatex: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/533382/2388. soul works okay for normal text but don't like many commands.

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer: Thanks. could you please tell me how can I use `\usepackage{lua-ul}`? I had the error that Latex cant find it. Then I downloaded it from (https://ctan.org/pkg/lua-ul) but it didn't contain lua-ul.sty. So I found (https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/lua-ul/) from (https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/180). But after putting these file beside my manuscript.tex I have the error of `lua-ul.lua:73: in main chunk
 [C]: in function 'require'
 [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.30 \directlua{require'lua-ul'}`

Comment: don't install manually, use the package manager of your tex system.

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer: Thanks. Your comment helped me a lot in different documents and situations. I would be appreciated if you merge and write your comments as an answer so I can accept it, if you like.